# My bitch keeps dragging objects into her whelping box

Tags: dogs, breeding

I have a bitch who is nursing a singleton in a whelping box that I built for her. She only leaves the box to eat; do her business; and oddly, find objects and bring them to the whelping box. The objects are typically small boxes (about the size of a box of macaroni), soda cans, mittens, or anything else of comparable size.

She's had three litters. She's done this every time.

However, last night she got into the recycling and brought back no less than 20 diet-coke cans, before she got into our winter clothing and absconded with 6 hats and 7 gloves.

The diet-coke cans were rinsed out thoroughly (so I don't think there was any especially appealing residue in them).

Why does she do this?